# The meaning of " half a workshopful of "

Tags: meaning

> Somewhere in the Other World, where there are books and pictures and
> plays and shop windows to look at, and thousands of men who spend
> their lives in building up all four, lives a gentleman who writes real
> stories about the real insides of people; and his name is Mr. Walter
> Besant. But he will insist upon treating his ghosts - he has published
> **half a workshopful of** them - with levity. He makes his ghost-seers talk familiarly, and, in some cases, flirt outrageously, with the
> phantoms.

This is from "My Own Ghost Story" by Rudyard Kipling。

What "half a workshopful of " mean?

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit tricky, because I'm not familiar with the story, and this isn't a very common way to say things, so it's unclear whether there's a larger context than what you've quoted here.  However, just based on this portion of the text you've supplied:

First, it's worth noting that "workshopful" is really not a common/normal word in modern English (and I'm not sure if it ever was common, to be honest), but it follows a well-established pattern so it's possible to understand what is meant anyway (which I suspect Kipling was relying on).  The suffix "-ful" here attached to another word basically just means "an amount which would fill (that space or volume)", so for example "a cupful" is "enough to fill a cup", "a cartful" is "enough to fill a cart", etc.  So in this case, "half a workshopful" means "enough to fill half of a workshop".

In this usage, since it's saying he's "published" half a workshopful, the implication (to me, at least) is that it's actually talking about how many *books* he has published, and is really saying "he's published enough books (about them) to fill half of (his) workshop".

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed answer!